# How to implement permission control in java?

Tags: java, permissions, spring-security

We developed a application, and need to implement permission control, which means someone can only search specific records in database:

1. staff can only search their own records.
2. supervisor can search records of his subordinate.
3. supervisor can see the "approve" button to approve the application
4. while staff can only submit application.

I know spring security, but actually how can we use the spring security to implement the function above?

We can implement the permission control with SQL, which means select his role first, and then select all his subordinate's records like this:

```
select * from table where staffid in (.......)
```

But this method seems just too raw, and hard to maintain. So my question is: is there any framework and practice that we can use to implement a decent permission control mechanism? How do you implement permission control in your application?

Answer (score 2):

**1)  staff can only search their own records.
2)  supervisor can search records of his subordinate.**

These seem like rules you'd have to implement at the DAO layer

**3)  supervisor can see the "approve" button to approve the application**

--This can be accomplished through UI Role-based rendering in JSF

**4)  while staff can only submit application.**

Spring Security Method Interceptors can be used here:  http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/secure-object-impls.html

Comment: do you mean to control access at DAO layer ?  pass in a supervisor then do all business in DAO?

Comment: The nature of those rules seem like they can only be implemented by either role-based filtering of the query results, or by directly restricting the query.  I'd think it would make more sense to do the later.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, it seems that there are three different types of permission control, have you ever experience other cases ?

Comment: You can provide security on every layer of your web application.  Spring Security is a good solution for mid-tier layers like protecting service calls.  What you use for each layer depends on your stack implementation.  What does your dev stack look like?

Comment: do you mean I should add a function in DAO layer like :getApplicationsBySupervisorID(String id)? and implement it with my own logic ?

Comment: You could have two methods, since you are only implementing two scenarios based on roles.  So getOwnRecords(long id)  --> StaffRole, and getAllRecords(long id)  -->SupervisorRole.  Protect each call with Spring Role Based Method interception in your business layer.  Decide on which service call to make based on role.  Of course you could also just have one service call getRecords(long id), and in your service impl decide which query restrictions to use based on role.  I'd actually probably do that, its more flexible.  Any help beyond that, I'd have to really dive into your code!

Comment: Thanks! Protect each call with Spring Role Based Method interception in your business layer. Why do I need to add this mechanism ? what benefit will this mechanism provide ?

Comment: Read that link I posted.  Security around infrastructure beans are configured automatically for you so you don't really need to know about the implementation classes.

Answer (score 0):

Using postgres databases,
you can inherit tables from tables. i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE access{
  admin bool default false,
  supervisor bool default false,
  staff_user_id bigint default null,
   ...
}
CREATE TABLE flower(
  flower_id serial,
  name varchar(24)
)inherits (access)
```

And then you can create an update/delete trigger, and differend connection-users.

This may be an solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the entities "Role" and "Business data" must be kept independent in DB - Instead of making multiple calls to database, Your select queries can join the role table and select only appropriate data.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at [Spring Security ACLs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/domain-acls.html) if you haven't already decided it is too complicated.